# Подсчет полного дохода подкомпаний TreeView

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, treeview

У меня есть `TreeView` с компаниями. Каждая компания может иметь дочерные компании каждая дочерная компания может иметь свом дочерные компании и это может продолжаться до бесконечности. У каждой компании есть собственные доходы, и еще есть `fullEarnings` которое равняется сумме всех доходов дочерных компаний этой компании.

Мне нужно рассчитать прибыль для каждой компании, если известно собственный заработок каждой компании.

Пример:

```
CompanyName  | OwnEarnings | FullEarnings

 -Company1   | 25K$        | 53K$
 --Company2  | 13K$        | 18K$
 ---Company3 | 5K$
 --Company4  | 10K$
```

У меня есть столбец  `ParentID` в базе данных, значения которого ссылаются на идентификатор родительской компании.

Как я могу это сделать? Может быть, с помощью рекурсии?